# Will removing items from array while looping through it breake the loop, and what can I do about it?

Tags: javascript

I'm looping through an array like this.

```
onScreenData.getTasks().array.forEach(function (task, taski, array) {
    if(task.checked){
        myTasks.addTask(task, state.name)
        onScreenData.removeTask(taski);
    }
})
```

`onScreenData.removeTask()` contains `tasks.array.splice(index, 1);`. Tasks.array is the same array as the one getting looped through. When `tasks.array.splice(index, 1);` is run, the loop stops instantly. What can be done about this?

Comment: @Kristoffer You push the array items to new array. Then use that for your program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the ECMA Script 5.1 standard Specification for [`Array.prototype.forEach`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.18),

> The range of elements processed by forEach is set before the first call to callbackfn. Elements which are appended to the array after the call to forEach begins will not be visited by callbackfn. If existing elements of the array are changed, their value as passed to callback will be the value at the time forEach visits them; **elements that are deleted after the call to forEach begins and before being visited are not visited.**

To understand this better, please check the following code

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];

a.forEach(function(currentItem, idx, array) {
    console.log(a.length, currentItem, idx, array);
    a.splice(idx, 1);
});

console.log(a);
```

It outputs,

```
4 1 0 [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
3 3 1 [ 2, 3, 4 ]
[ 2, 4 ]
```

In the first iteration, `a.length` is `4`, current item is `1` and the index is `0`. This is perfectly fine. And we remove the element at index `0` in the first iteration.

In the second iteration, since the first element is removed, length of the array shrinks to 3, `2` becomes the first element and the current index is `1`. Now, the item corresponding to index `1` is `3`. So, that is removed in this iteration.

Now, the length of the array is `2` and the current index becomes `2`. Since, we cannot access the element at index 2, when the size of the array itself is `2`, JavaScript breaks out of the loop.

So, effectively we have skipped the elements next to the elements being removed.

*That is why we should not alter the array while iterating it.*

The best option here is to use, [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), like this

```
onScreenData.array = onScreenData.getTasks().array.filter(function (task) {
    if(task.checked) {
        myTasks.addTask(task, state.name)
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: I saw one suggestion that was to loop the array backwards, is this soultion better?

Comment: Also, how do I use this to remove the tasks?

Comment: @KristofferNolgren I am editing the answer to include why removing while iterating is bad also, check the `filter` version. We are assigning the result to `onScreenData.array`, right? That will have only the filtered data. So, if the `task.checked` is `true`, then those items will be removed.

Comment: very userful and pedagogic!

Comment: Just to be clear: after the filtering is done, I loop through my new array and onScreenData.removeTask(taski);?

Comment: @KristofferNolgren You don't need to remove tasks explicitly again, after filtering. After filtering do `console.log(onScreenData.array);` you will see the difference

Comment: But onScreenData.removeTask() is a method that does stuff to data in the onScreenData-class?

Comment: @KristofferNolgren If it does only `tasks.array.splice(index, 1)`, then `filter` itself is enough for this case.